# Does StringTie use exon length for gene abundance or complete gene length?

Tags: quantification, stringtie

I'm currently using [StringTie](https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/stringtie/) with option `-A` for calculating gene abundance (I'm interested in TPM). While checking the manual, I couldn't find any reference to the record type StringTie uses to calculate this value. Does anyone know if it is total gene length or total effective (i.e. exon) gene length?